# При использовании import requests совместно с Selenium сразу после запуска браузера и загрузки сайта, браузер закрывается

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Т.е. выполнятся driver.get(), загружается сайт и сразу же браузер закрывается, не выполняя необходимых действий.

Использую BeautifulSoup для получения информации с сайта, а Selenium для заполнения формы на другом сайте.

Если не использовать requests, Selenium работает, как должен.

Использую браузер Chrome.

Даже если в работающий код вставить `import requests`, который даже не будет использоваться, Selenium ведет себя также, как описано выше.

Вот с кодом:
Работает:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    chrome_driver_path = 'C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    
    driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/')
```

Не работает:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import requests
    chrome_driver_path = 'C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
    
    driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: Не работает, потому что в коде у вас ошибка. Где именно не подскажу, так как вы код не включили в вопрос.

Comment: Даже если в работающий код вставить import requests, который даже не будет использоваться, Selenium ведет себя также, как описано выше.